# In HTML, what is the opposite to <strong>?

Tags: html, xhtml, tags

Does there exist an opposite tag to `<strong>` in HTML? Or will it be introduced in HTML5?

Comment: What do you mean with "opposite"?.. Maybe inside a `<strong>` tag making some text back to normal style?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? NOT having <strong> text means you have normal text... :S

Comment: No. You may consider `<small>`, however the HTML 5 specs say there: "To mark text as not emphasized or important, simply do not mark it up with the em or strong elements respectively." Can you give a use case where you'd want to use such a de-emphasized text?

Comment: @RoTaRa - Perhaps a legal disclaimer? You know...the part of the website that actually tells the truth. :-)

Comment: An example use case could be the answer time in comments here on SO, ie. <weak>53 secs ago</weak>.

Comment: @T.E.D.: That would be an acceptable use of `small` IMHO.

Comment: @Muleskinner: That isn't something that should be "de-emphasized" IMHO.

Comment: if you are using a css class which does all you need, except that it implies <strong> which is the only thing you don't want. Then you want to be able to reverse the effect.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> To mark text as not emphasized or important, simply do not mark it up with the em or strong elements respectively.

Source: [HTML 5: The small element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element)

Comment: Feature creep: HTML has 6 different tags for teletype, but not one for unimportant text...

Answer (score 18):

No, there's no opposite. Regular text would be the closest unless you create a custom css class like:

```
span.weak {
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Which would, of course, allow you to have markup that looks like:

```
This is some <span class="weak">very weak</span> text.
```

Comment: why are you talking about presentation and CSS while the HTML tag is only related to it's semantics?

Comment: @wildcard - Because, while not directly related, a properly named CSS class used in conjunction with the span tag can provide an extra bit of semantics when there's no other option available.

Answer (score 11):

`<strong>` stands for “strong emphasis”.

There is also *normal* emphasis, i.e. `<em>` and of course no emphasis – normal text.

To *de*emphasise is not a common semantic need that has spawned an own, accepted typographic style so there is no special tag for it. You need to go the route via `<span>`s and CSS, e.g.:

```
This is is <strong>very important</strong>. You should remember it.
<span class="deemphasized">This, on the other hand, isn’t important
at all. Ignore it.</span>
```

Printed slightly smaller and with a lighter colour (assuming the normal colour is black, and the background is white):

```
.deemphasized { color: #444; font-size: 0.9em; }
```

Comment: again, what does HTML tag has to do with CSS and typography? It's all about semantics.

Comment: @wildcard Of course it’s semantics, I never claimed anything else. When I said “common typographic style” I was referring to the fact that this is a common semantic element that has an established typography. (But I have cleared the formulation up to make this clearer.)

Answer (score 2):

No.  The opposite of strong would be normal text.

Answer (score 2):

Use normal text, without any `<strong>` or `<em>` tags; that would be an appropriate opposite. You could style something with CSS, or use `<small>`, but that's not the best solution.

Comment: whats not the best solution, <small>?

Comment: As pointed out by the accepted answer, the specification explicitly marks `<small>` as being inappropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a whole **block of text** that is less important than the main content you can use `aside`. But don't go using it all over the place unless there's a real meaning to it being supplementary content. Consider how a screen reader should react to your site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span style="font-weight:lighter">`

Example:

```html
<p>
  <strong>
    This is bold text
    <span style="font-weight:lighter">
       This is regular text
    </span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.